# groupby aggregate mean in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have a 2D tensor:

```py
samples = torch.Tensor([
    [0.1, 0.1],    #-> group / class 1
    [0.2, 0.2],    #-> group / class 2
    [0.4, 0.4],    #-> group / class 2
    [0.0, 0.0]     #-> group / class 0
])
```

and a label for each sample corresponding to a class:

```py
labels = torch.LongTensor([1, 2, 2, 0])
```

so `len(samples) == len(labels)`. Now I want to calculate the mean for each class / label. Because there are 3 classes (0, 1 and 2) the final vector should have dimension `[n_classes, samples.shape[1]]` So the expected solution should be:

```py
result == torch.Tensor([
    [0.1, 0.1],
    [0.3, 0.3], # -> mean of [0.2, 0.2] and [0.4, 0.4]
    [0.0, 0.0]
])
```

**Question**: How can this be done in pure pytorch (i.e. no numpy so that I can autograd) and ideally without for loops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is form an  mxn matrix (m=num classes, n=num samples) which will select the appropriate weights, and scale the mean appropriately. Then you can perform a matrix multiplication between your newly formed matrix and the samples matrix.

Given your labels, your matrix should be (each row is a class number, each class a sample number and its weight):

```
[[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000],
 [1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
 [0.0000, 0.5000, 0.5000, 0.0000]]
```

Which you can form as follows:

```
M = torch.zeros(labels.max()+1, len(samples))
M[labels, torch.arange(len(samples)] = 1
M = torch.nn.functional.normalize(M, p=1, dim=1)
torch.mm(M, samples)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.1000, 0.1000],
        [0.3000, 0.3000]])
```

Note that the output means are correctly sorted in class order.

Why does `M[labels, torch.arange(len(samples))] = 1` work?

This is performing a broadcast operation between the labels and the number of samples. Essentially, we are generating a 2D index for every element in labels: the first specifies which of the m classes it belongs to, and the second simply specifies its index position (from 1 to N). Another way would be top explicitly generate all the 2D indices:

```
twoD_indices = []
for count, label in enumerate(labels):
  twoD_indices.append((label, count))
```

Comment: Good solution; for those confused about `M[labels, torch.arange(4] = 1`, it is essentially just generating the indices for the columns for assignment. So at a high level, we are moving column by column in the matrix (across the samples), putting 1 where appropriate to indicate its class

Answer (score 4):

Reposting here an answer from @ptrblck_de in the [Pytorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/groupby-aggregate-mean-in-pytorch/45335/2?u=elyase)

```
labels = labels.view(labels.size(0), 1).expand(-1, samples.size(1))

unique_labels, labels_count = labels.unique(dim=0, return_counts=True)

res = torch.zeros_like(unique_labels, dtype=torch.float).scatter_add_(0, labels, samples)
res = res / labels_count.float().unsqueeze(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As previous solutions do not work for the case of sparse groups (e.g., not all the groups are in the data), I made one :)

```
def groupby_mean(value:torch.Tensor, labels:torch.LongTensor) -> (torch.Tensor, torch.LongTensor):
    """Group-wise average for (sparse) grouped tensors

    Args:
        value (torch.Tensor): values to average (# samples, latent dimension)
        labels (torch.LongTensor): labels for embedding parameters (# samples,)

    Returns: 
        result (torch.Tensor): (# unique labels, latent dimension)
        new_labels (torch.LongTensor): (# unique labels,)

    Examples:
        >>> samples = torch.Tensor([
                             [0.15, 0.15, 0.15],    #-> group / class 1
                             [0.2, 0.2, 0.2],    #-> group / class 3
                             [0.4, 0.4, 0.4],    #-> group / class 3
                             [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]     #-> group / class 0
                      ])
        >>> labels = torch.LongTensor([1, 5, 5, 0])
        >>> result, new_labels = groupby_mean(samples, labels)

        >>> result
        tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.1500, 0.1500, 0.1500],
            [0.3000, 0.3000, 0.3000]])

        >>> new_labels
        tensor([0, 1, 5])
    """
    uniques = labels.unique().tolist()
    labels = labels.tolist()

    key_val = {key: val for key, val in zip(uniques, range(len(uniques)))}
    val_key = {val: key for key, val in zip(uniques, range(len(uniques)))}

    labels = torch.LongTensor(list(map(key_val.get, labels)))

    labels = labels.view(labels.size(0), 1).expand(-1, value.size(1))

    unique_labels, labels_count = labels.unique(dim=0, return_counts=True)
    result = torch.zeros_like(unique_labels, dtype=torch.float).scatter_add_(0, labels, value)
    result = result / labels_count.float().unsqueeze(1)
    new_labels = torch.LongTensor(list(map(val_key.get, unique_labels[:, 0].tolist())))
    return result, new_labels
```

Answer (score 0):

## For 3D Tensors:

For those, who are interested. I expanded @yhenon's answer to the case, where `labels` is a 2D tensor and `samples` is a 3D Tensor. This might be useful, if you want to execute this operation in batches (as I do). But it comes with a caveat (see at the end).

```py
M = torch.zeros(labels.shape[0], labels.max()+1, labels.shape[1])
M[torch.arange(len(labels))[:,None], labels, torch.arange(labels.size(1))] = 1
M = torch.nn.functional.normalize(M, p=1, dim=-1)
result = M@samples
```

```py
samples = torch.Tensor([[
    [0.1, 0.1],    #-> group / class 1
    [0.2, 0.2],    #-> group / class 2
    [0.4, 0.4],    #-> group / class 2
    [0.0, 0.0]     #-> group / class 0
], [
    [0.5, 0.5],    #-> group / class 0
    [0.2, 0.2],    #-> group / class 1
    [0.4, 0.4],    #-> group / class 2
    [0.1, 0.1]     #-> group / class 3
]])

labels = torch.LongTensor([[1, 2, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Output:

```py
>>> result
tensor([[[0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.1000, 0.1000],
         [0.3000, 0.3000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000]],

        [[0.5000, 0.5000],
         [0.2000, 0.2000],
         [0.4000, 0.4000],
         [0.1000, 0.1000]]])
```

**Be careful:** Now, `result[0]` has a length of 4 (instead of 3 in @yhenon's answer), because `labels[1]` contains a 3. The last row contains only 0s. If you don't except 0s in the last rows of your resulting tensor, you can use this code and deal with the 0s later.