# groupby aggregate product in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have the same problem as [groupby aggregate mean in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154604/groupby-aggregate-mean-in-pytorch). However, I want to create the **product** of my tensors inside each group (or labels). Unfortunately, I couldn't find a native PyTorch function that could solve my problem, like a hypothetical `scatter_prod_` for products (equivalent to `scatter_add_` for sums), which was the function used in one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56156724/10714156).

Recycling the example code from [@elyase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154604/groupby-aggregate-mean-in-pytorch)'s question, consider the 2D tensor:

```
samples = torch.Tensor([
    [0.1, 0.1],    #-> group / class 1
    [0.2, 0.2],    #-> group / class 2
    [0.4, 0.4],    #-> group / class 2
    [0.0, 0.0]     #-> group / class 0
])
```

with labels where it is true that `len(samples) == len(labels)`

```
labels = torch.LongTensor([1, 2, 2, 0])
```

So my expected output is:

```
res == torch.Tensor([
    [0.0, 0.0],
    [0.1, 0.1], 
    [0.8, 0.8] # -> PRODUCT of [0.2, 0.2] and [0.4, 0.4]
])
```

Here the question is, again, following [@elyase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154604/groupby-aggregate-mean-in-pytorch)'s question, how can this be done in **pure PyTorch** (i.e. no numpy so that I can autograd) and ideally without for loops?

Crossposted in [PyTorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/groupby-aggregate-product-in-pytorch/167398).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `scatter_` function to calculate the product of the tensors in each group.

```py
samples = torch.Tensor([
    [0.1, 0.1],    #-> group / class 1
    [0.2, 0.2],    #-> group / class 2
    [0.4, 0.4],    #-> group / class 2
    [0.0, 0.0]     #-> group / class 0
])

labels = torch.LongTensor([1,2,2,0])

label_size = 3
sample_dim = samples.size(1)

index = labels.unsqueeze(1).repeat((1, sample_dim))

res = torch.ones(label_size, sample_dim, dtype=samples.dtype)
res.scatter_(0, index, samples, reduce='multiply')
```

`res`:

```bash
tensor([[0.0000, 0.0000],
        [0.1000, 0.1000],
        [0.0800, 0.0800]])
```